# Programmatically Add Font-Awesome Icons to Category Widget

Tags: functions, widgets, filters, icon

I use the Categories widget on my sidebar(s) and I would like to display a [Font Awesome icon](http://fontawesome.io/) next to each category listed in the widget.  The icon would be the same for all categories, for now, but I would like to give each category it's own unique icon in the future.

I would like to modify the Categories widget using code in my **functions.php** file to add the icon by inserting markup like `<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>` into category's link/anchor element *after* the category's title. I could accomplish this via CSS, but in doing so I lose the ability to programmatically determine which icon to display, along with the flexibility for other improvements/changes that I may wish to make in the future.

Basically, I wish to achieve this effect:

```
Cat 1          >

Cat 2          >

Cat 3          >
```

<sub>**(The greater-than symbol '>' represents the icon placement relative to the category title)**</sub>

I have Font Awesome enqueued in the *functions.php* file using the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook as follows, and it loads and displays the icons perfectly.  Note that I do not use any Font Awesome plugin built for WordPress.

```
/* Enqueue Scripts
-----------------------------------------------------------------*/
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'essentials_enqueue_scripts' );
function essentials_enqueue_scripts() {
    /* jQuery */
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery_ui', "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . "://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/2.0.3/jquery-ui.min.js", false, null);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'waypoints', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/waypoints.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'essentials_main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/essentials_main.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'essentials_show_stuff', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/essentials_show_stuff.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
    /* Google Fonts */
    wp_register_style('GoogleFonts','http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700,800|Bad+Script');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'GoogleFonts');
    /* Font Awesome Fonts */
    wp_register_style('Font Awesome','//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'Font Awesome'); 
}
```

Despite my best research efforts, I was unable to find a solution to modify the categories widget.

Comment: Please clarify your question to explain how it is *WordPress-specific*, rather than merely **CSS**. Also, please edit your question to include **what you have done/tried so far**. How are you including/enqueueing the FontAwesome font?

Comment: Edit added to answer your questions.

Comment: "*This is WordPress specific due to me wanting to customize WordPress categories via the FUNCTIONS.PHP file*" - given that the ultimate solution is still **entirely CSS**, the question still isn't WordPress specific. It merely happens *in the context* of WordPress. Your limitation of wanting a function to pop into `functions.php`, which excludes the most plausible answers, also makes this question too localized. Perhaps if you edited the question to focus on **how to enqueue custom CSS**, it would be on-topic for WPSE?

Comment: Again, I don't want a CSS solution.  My limitation also expands my future for this need.  I like icons, and others may want icons.  In the future, I may build an options page for myself to add SPECIFIC icons, not just a single icon.  I have absolutely no intention of using CSS on this, I didn't want a background-image, and I did compliment someone on doing the :after {content} but again, it's not what I'm wanting.  This is SPECIFIC to WordPress, I know how to do it in CSS and how to do it in HTML.  I didn't know how to do it in WordPress by editing the Widget via a custom function.

Comment: The CSS `content` attribute *isn't a background image*, it's *content*. And a CSS solution is the *best* way to implement - even if you want to expose end-user options. What I'm trying to help you see is that your unnecessary and arbitrary constraints are making the problem unnecessarily difficult.

Comment: As @Chip is stating, your question as it stands is strictly regarding a CSS implementation - you are very clearly asking how to display a single character out of an icon-based font-face. The way in which this is accomplished is by placing that character in the HTML and applying the font face to the character (or a container element) using CSS. No part of this process has anything to do with WordPress. Nowhere in your question do you state that you wish to add this character by modifying WordPress's output. Doing so is excessive and very likely unnecessary if your question is accurate.

Comment: Expanding on my previous comment, birgire's answer that you have accepted below ***is a CSS implementation*** - the only thing different is he is adding the CSS-styled element using PHP and regular expressions rather than simply directly inserting it in your template markup. This incurs a resource overhead for loading and executing the PHP that there is absolutely no need for. Please re-factor your question to imply that you wish to add this character programmatically and server-side if this is truly the case. It would aide greatly if you would state ***why*** you have these requirements, too.

Comment: Not seeking to alienate you here or anything - just trying to see your question better defined and bring it up to snuff with our community's standards - but you should remove the bit about *"I really don't want to re-invent the wheel here, so if I could just pop something into my themes function.php file that would be great"* and add information regarding what you have attempted so far. As it stands, your question is *very clearly* asking our community to hand you code without showing effort on your part, which is against our standards. Please see [ask] for more on our standards.

Comment: Ok, well if this **edit** I just did doesn't suffice.. then you may delete this question.  I would prefer no one to lose their reputation gained through this.  If you could close it, that may be the better alternative.

Comment: "*I do not really wish to have to put 25 lines of code into my CSS to display the different icons.*" - the real problem with this is that it makes your question *too localized*, because you restrict the best and most obvious solution: CSS. I simply can't fathom why 25 lines of CSS is less-desirable than multiple filters, and 50 lines of PHP string-replacement.

Comment: Oh well, maybe the CSS solution is the obvious for you.  It is not the obvious for me, I'm looking at it on a different scale, so my interpretation of the steps to get there are going to vary.  So, if this was not localized, it would not fall under *WordPress Specific*.  I have a problem that relates to me, it might not relate to you, but not every problem does.  I came here for a **WordPress** solution to something, and I got it.  I don't know why we are still battling over something that has been answered.  I'm satisfied with the answer.. leave it at that.

Comment: "I don't know why we are still battling over something that has been answered." - because Stack Exchange sites are not support forums, but Question and Answer sites intended to build a knowledge base for general/universal application. Your arbitrary limitation makes the question not universally useful, which is why it renders the question as too localized. And while you're free to accept whatever answer best suits your needs personally, the accepted answer is, quite frankly, terrible for the vast majority of people who need to incorporate icon fonts.

Comment: Well flag it then, and we will see what happens.  I'm not going to battle over something.  I tried to delete my question and it will not let me, so let the moderators decide the appropriate action from here.

Comment: @MrJustin, I believe that your edits have not only brought your question on-topic, but also provided the necessary constraints that made selecting a non-CSS implementation a logical choice. I have changed my down-vote to an up-vote. I greatly appreciate your patience through all of this, and willingness to revise your question for the betterment of our community!

Comment: I have provided one final revision in order to distill the question down to it's most basic and direct form, and in a manner that will hopefully prevent future readers seeking to simply add an icon from implementing the more complex accepted answer below.

Comment: @bosco I appreciate your revision, and while I did not accept it, I find it more than satisfactory.  I appreciate the up vote.  I really had no intention, and do not like to argue.  I am glad we could come to a reasonable solution.  I will put forth a better effort when establishing my original questions to make describe **exactly** what I am attempting to do.  Once again, thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Assumptions:

You don't explain how you want to install the Font Awesome package, so I just assume for the moment that you use the plugin [Font Awesome Icons](http://wordpress.org/plugins/font-awesome/).

You wrote:

> Before anyone says use a background image, I do not want to do that. I
>   would like it to be physical.

so I assume you want to use the `<i>` tag directly, for example:

```
<i class="fa icon-caret-right"></i>
```

after each category link in the *widget category list*.

### Idea:

You can use the `wp_list_categories` filter to modify the output of the widget category list.

### Example:

Here is a simple example how to inject it into the category list via the `wp_list_categories` filter:

```
/**
 * Inject Font Awesome <i> tag after each widget category link
 *
 * @param string $output
 * @return string $output
 */

 function custom_wp_list_categories( $output )
 {  
     remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ ); 
     return str_ireplace( '</li>', '<i class="fa icon-caret-right"></i></li>', $output);
 }

 add_action( 'widgets_init', function(){
     add_filter( 'wp_list_categories', 'custom_wp_list_categories' );
 });
```

This will give you an output similar to this one:

[image: catlist]

Comment: Great bit of code, I will check it out when I return in a bit.  I will post the results.

Comment: just remember to adjust the class name to your needs ;-) I used the `icon-caret-right` because that's the class naming rule according to the plugin. In other cases it might be  `fa-caret-right`.

Comment: `return str_ireplace( '</li>', '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></li>', $output);` worked, but `return str_ireplace( '</a></li>', '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a></li>', $output);` did not.

Comment: ok, you want to add it inside the `<a></a>` tag, then please try this:  `return preg_replace( '/<\/a>\s*<\/li>/i', ' <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a></li>', $output );`

Comment: Ok, now I'm lost on the new part.. how exactly does that work?  I understand the last bit, but not the first bit.

Comment: Not going to downvote a legitimate solution/attempt to help the OP, but really: using PHP string-replacement when a simple CSS rule would suffice seems to be overkill.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being more specific in my original 'Question' but this isn't going to be limited to something as small as putting the icon in there.  This is going to be expanded out in the future, and CSS didn't salute my needs, as why I posted on here ;).

Comment: @MrJustin thanks for the voting, I'm also impressed by the ingenious answers provided by the other users.  ps: `\s*` matches any whitespace character, like space, tab and newline.

Comment: @MrJustin could you please expand your question to detail these "future needs" for which CSS is insufficient? As it stands your question is specifically regarding CSS and is not tied to WordPress, and as such is sitting on shifty grounds for being closed as off-topic.

Comment: I might also add that a WordPress filter was excessive enough given the scope of MrJustin's question. I hardly think leading him into regular expressions is a good idea... I can't help but feel regular expressions lie polar opposite to the simplicity of a static CSS implementation. I fear for any future WPSEpedian who comes here looking to display a single character out of an icon-font and winds up with a chunk of regular expressions in their backend. Have pity on the n00bs!

Comment: one could also use: `return str_ireplace( '</a>', ' <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>', $output);`

Comment: @birgire, I appreciate that addition!

Answer (score 5):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16994606/modify-default-wordpress-category-widget) contains a fairly simple CSS solution.

Essentially, you'd add the following to your stylesheet:

```
.cat-item cat-item-7 {
     list-style-image: url('my-epic-news-icon');
}


cat-item cat-item-11 {
     list-style-image: url('my-epic-jquery-icon');
}
```

etc

Yes, it's not a very dynamic solution, but your categories aren't likely to change I suppose.

Comment: That the answer is pure CSS is indicative of the underlying question being off-topic for WPSE. That said: I think your CSS selectors do not have proper syntax. You should use `.cat-item.cat-item-7` - or, since the same icon font image is intended to be used for all list items, just use `.cat-item`. Also: a font icon would use the `content` attribute, and would target the `:after` pseudo-class, such as: `.cat-item:after { content: '\f18d'; }`.

Comment: Fair points. Yes I made a mistake in the syntax. Are we sure OP wants the same image, or different one per category? (That's how I understood it). I just wanted to propose the easiest solution, although that does take the qu/answer off-topic.

Comment: Not the solution I was looking for as I had said I didn't want to use a background and that I would want the icon after the text.  While it may not be a background, it's still an image, and not Font Awesome.  Good solution, but not the solution for me.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you want to use [the `fa-chevron-right` icon](http://fontawesome.io/icon/chevron-right/), you simply need to target the list item via CSS. Use the `:after` pseudo-class:

```
.list-item:after {
    font-family: FontAwesome; // or whatever the font awesome family is registered as
    content: '\f054';
}
```

### Edit

So, to give an idea of how you might pass dynamic CSS (which can be easily adapted to a custom Plugin option) via a callback, here's an example:

(Note: "plugin" and "theme" are interchangeable below.)

First, we'll modify the CSS to target list items inside of a Widget specifically. WordPress adds a class, `.widget`, to the Widget container. So you can target that:

```
.widget .list-item:after {}
```

Or, if this will all be wrapped up in a Plugin that registers a custom Widget, then you can target the CSS class that you define in your custom Widget, via the `$widget_ops` array:

```
$widget_ops = array( 
    'classname' => 'custom-widget-classname', 
    'description' => __( 'Custom Widget Description', 'namespace' ) 
);
```

So, you can target that custom classname:

```
.custom-widget-classname .list-item:after {}
```

Or, if you want to target the core "Categories" Widget, you can use the `.widget_categories` class. We'll go with that approach for the example.

We're going to put it inside a callback, hooked into `wp_head`, though you can just as easily use `wp_print_styles`:

```
function pluginslug_fontawesome_styles() {
    // Code will go here
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'pluginslug_fontawesome_styles' );
```

Inside, we're just going to output a stylesheet, with our rule from above:

```
function pluginslug_fontawesome_styles() {
    ?>
<script type="text/css">
.widget_categories .list-item:after {
    font-family: FontAwesome; // or whatever the font awesome family is registered as
    content: '\f054';
}
</script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'pluginslug_fontawesome_styles' );
```

At this point, you're done. Easy peasy. But, since you're already inside a PHP function, you can easily make this stylesheet *dynamic*, by using a variable:

```
function pluginslug_fontawesome_styles() {

    // Define list-style icon variable
    $list_item_icon = '\f054';

    // ...snip:
    content: <?php echo $list_item_icon; ?>;
```

So now, it's a simple matter to use a custom Plugin option value, just by passing it to the variable:

```
function pluginslug_fontawesome_styles() {

    // Get Plugin options, assumed to be an array
    $plugin_options = get_option( 'pluginslug_plugin_options' );

    // Define list-style icon variable
    $list_item_icon = $plugin_options['list_item_icon'];

    // Output stylesheet
    ?>
<script type="text/css">
.widget_categories .list-item:after {
    font-family: FontAwesome; // or whatever the font awesome family is registered as
    content: <?php echo $list_item_icon; ?>;
}
</script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'pluginslug_fontawesome_styles' );
```

So that's it! Dynamic CSS, outputting an actual icon (not a background image), pulling from a Plugin option.

And since it's just CSS, it's easily extensible to pretty much any selector you can imagine - not just limited to a list item inside of a Widget.

Comment: Very nice option, but I wanted a function.  :)

Comment: You know that you can wrap up CSS rules in a callback, and enqueue at `wp_head` or `wp_print_styles`, right? But that part of the implementation is a separate question and outside of the scope of the question as-written.

Comment: Yes I do know how to enqueue.  However, I don't want to use CSS.  I know it's a quick and efficient way of doing it, and I do compliment you on that.. but maybe I should be using the words 'need a' instead of 'want a' when it comes to the function.

Comment: Please see the edited question. I added an example to show how the entire thing really can be handled via CSS, dynamically, extensibly, and able to account for custom Plugin options.

Comment: Right, but now, what if I wanted to have the 'icon' **float** to the right?  In my normal CSS I have attached it to `li a:after {content}` and tried: `text-align: right` and it did nothing for me.  What I mean by this, to clarify, is what if I wanted all of the icons on the right of the LI with the text on the left.  Say the ul/li was set to 250px, the text is always a link, but I had it set to block. Then I added the 'icon' and wanted the icon to sit to the right of the li.  With the <i...></i> I can easily float it.

Comment: To answer that specific question: instead of `li a:after`, use `li a:before`. But style/positioning of elements: aside from knowing the markup provided by WordPress (including the specific CSS classes, and the list HTML markup), these are CSS/HTML questions. Interestingly, the answer you marked as accepted uses nothing other than CSS. (The enqueued Font Awesome stylesheet that makes use of the class you add via the string replacement uses the `:after` pseudo-class and the `content` attribute to output the icon.)

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
// If you're using the widget only on specific pages,
// you might want to use some appropriate conditions here
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome',
        '//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css');
});

function wpse_128247_font_awesome_categories($cat_name) {
    // Define your desired icon here
    $icon = ' <i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i>';

    return $cat_name.$icon;
} // function wpse_128247_font_awesome_categories

function wpse_128247_add_filter($cat_args) {
    add_filter('list_cats', 'wpse_128247_font_awesome_categories');

    // Since we're hijacking this filter, we just pass through its data
    return $cat_args;
} // function wpse_128247_add_filter
add_filter('widget_categories_args', 'wpse_128247_add_filter');

function wpse_128247_remove_filter($output) {
    remove_filter('list_cats', 'wpse_128247_font_awesome_categories');

    // Since we're hijacking this filter, we just pass through its data
    return $output;
} // function wpse_128247_remove_filter
add_filter('wp_list_categories', 'wpse_128247_remove_filter');
```

First, we enqueue the font awesome styles. Then, we hijack some filters to add/remove our own filter for the category listing. That's it.

---

**// EDIT:**
Without the comments, adapted to the fact that you already have enqueued Font Awesome, using closures, and letting the filter remove itself, the code reads like the following:

```
function wpse_128247_font_awesome_categories($cat_name) {
    remove_filter(current_filter(), __FUNCTION__);
    return $cat_name.' <i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i>';
} // function wpse_128247_font_awesome_categories

function wpse_128247_add_filter($cat_args) {
    add_filter('list_cats', 'wpse_128247_font_awesome_categories');
    return $cat_args;
} // function wpse_128247_add_filter
add_filter('widget_categories_args', 'wpse_128247_add_filter');
```

I would not call that *overkill*. But yes, my code consists of more lines than birgire's current solution.

Comment: Your solution wasn't bad, but an overkill compared to birgire's.  I already have Font-Awesome enqueued, sorry I didn't specify.

Comment: Yeah, that code is not an overkill, I will agree with that.  It probably just looked like more with the 4 functions instead of 2, and the amount of commenting.  I appreciate the commenting, I'm not downing that.  It just looked like a lot more :).

Comment: Since you are using remove_filter on the function that adds the icon it's only going to run a single time. This means an icon will only be added to the first item in the widget_categories list.