# Adding Font Awesome to WP Plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, wp-enqueue-style, wp-register-style

I'm trying to use font awesome icons for my plugin.  I've read this page in the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) and this [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128247/programmatically-add-font-awesome-icons-to-category-widget).

Here's what I've tried so far:

I've added this on ***wp-plug-in.php*** (or should it be somewhere else?)

> ```
> add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_styles' ); 
>   function wp_styles() {
>       wp_register_style( 'font-awesome', plugins_url( 'wp-plug-in/css/font-awesome.min.css' ) );
>       wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome' );
>   }
> ```

I'm hoping I could use it the usual way like:

> `<i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>`

But to no avail. It doesn't display anything at all. I know I'm missing out something and I'm hoping that someone could point it out and probably give me additional resources. 
Thank you.

**UPDATE**

It turned out the theme I had activated didn't have `<?php wp_head(); ?>` on the header.
 Lesson learned. :) Thanks a lot @Robert and @Abhik.

Comment: Did you check if font-awesome.min.css being added in website source code? I tried it and it's working fine. If it's being added in head section of website source then check it by adding this `<i class="fa fa-twitter" style="color:black;"></i>`. Does it show anything?

Comment: No, the css wasn't added in the source code. Do you think it might be a conflict?

Comment: Posted some instructions below. Please check and confirm if that's what you did? You can also include font awesome CDN URL if you do not want to host them yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you create `wp-plug-in/wp-plug-in.php` file in plugins folder and added this following code.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Load FontAwesome
 * Version:     1.0
 */

/* Exit if accessed directly */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

function wp_styles() {
    wp_register_style( 'font-awesome', plugins_url( 'wp-plug-in/css/font-awesome.min.css' ) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_styles' );
```

And added font awesome css and fonts in wp-plug-in/css folder?
And then activate this plugin from admin panel?

Can you not see font-awesome.min.css file in website source code? Search for it?

Comment: Hey, thanks.. I've checked and double-checked it: wp-plug-in/wp-plug-in.php(yes), code(added), font-awesome contents(added) and the plugin is activated.. Still not in the source code..

Comment: Do you have this website online? Where we can see it. Also turn on debugging mode by adding `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` in wp-config.php to see if there are any errors.

Comment: I just checked my theme and it turns out `<?php wp_head(); ?>` is missing. Thank you.

Comment: Oops... I should have known it. :) well, I am glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

You got to include the fonts too if you are delivering the css from your plugin. Or, just enqueue the font awesome css from their CDN.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_styles' ); 
function wp_styles() {
    wp_register_style( 'fontawesome', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css', array(), '4.2.0' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'fontawesome' );
}
```

Check the [Getting Started](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/) guide.